# Changing spring.datasource.url variable value conditionally within a Spring Boot controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to develop a microservices for different regions. So I already configured spring.datasource.url variable in my application.properties. If there is any situation occurs to retrieve data from another database, can I change the value of "spring.datasource.url" variable already setted in the application.properties?

Currently I added my application.properties file like following,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/<my_DB_Name>
spring.datasource.username=<my_username>
spring.datasource.password=<my_password>
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

In my application, there is some functionality which taking data from another DB. So can I conditionally change the url variable from my controller?

Comment: No. It is not possible. Why don't you declare two datasources and use one based on your situation

Comment: So what I can do for developing microservices for two different regions? Need to deploy application separate for different regions?

Comment: Currently my database design is horizontal division. One database for one region. and one for another region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option dynamic data source selection is to use [AbstractRoutingDatasource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html).

REACTION ON COMMENT1:
As this is not common use case, there aren't many examples. I didn't use it before myself. Your best bet is to look at [this ancient example by Mark Fisher](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/). Of course Spring was different beast at that time and you'll need to map this example onto modern APIs. Especially Java config instead of XML config used in example. But That is pretty easy.

REACTION ON COMMENT2:
You region DBs would be specified in `targetDataSources` map. Logic deciding which datasource to use would land in `determineCurrentLookupKey`, which would return lookup key into `targetDataSources`. You need to pass it from controller, so if you can't findany other mechanism how to inject state which will be used to pick up datasource, you still can use `@RequestScope` bean and pass it that way.

I believe the example is pretty clear and suitable for your use case (assuming that you finite amount of reagion DBs).

Comment: Can you give any good documentation for the implementation of this solution please ? , since i am new to spring world.

Comment: OK. let me check tutorial. Thank you for your response sir.

Comment: I checked that functionality. It is just directly injecting thorough bean configuration specified in the XML file , th dispatcher servlet.But I actually need to conditionally assign datasource url according to one particular type of user or user activity.This is actually my requirement.

Comment: I explained how you would fit the example onto your use case.